# Complex MySQL Credit Debit Balance

Tags: mysql

I got a table named "Stock" as shown below.

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| client_id |       date   |       credit  |    debit|
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
|         1 |   01-01-2015 |            50 |       0 |
|         2 |   01-01-2015 |           250 |       0 |
|         2 |   01-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         2 |   02-01-2015 |             0 |     500 |
|         1 |   02-01-2015 |             0 |      40 |
|         1 |   02-01-2015 |             0 |      80 |
|         3 |   05-01-2015 |          3000 |       0 |
|         2 |   06-01-2015 |             0 |     350 |
|         4 |   06-01-2015 |             0 |    1000 |
|         4 |   06-01-2015 |             0 |    2000 |
|         4 |   07-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         5 |   07-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         5 |   08-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         1 |   09-01-2015 |             0 |     100 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

The result I am expecting is something like:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+----------+
|client_id|  date     |Open_Balance | credit |  debit  | balance  |
+---------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+----------+
|       1 |01-01-2015 |           0 |     50 |       0 |       50 |
|       1 |02-01-2015 |          50 |      0 |      40 |       10 |
|       1 |02-01-2015 |          10 |      0 |      80 |      -70 |
|       1 |09-01-2015 |         -70 |      0 |     100 |     -170 |
|       2 |01-01-2015 |           0 |    250 |       0 |      250 |
|       2 |01-01-2015 |         250 |    500 |       0 |      750 |
|       2 |02-01-2015 |         750 |      0 |     500 |      250 |
|       2 |06-01-2015 |         250 |      0 |     350 |     -100 |  
|       3 |05-01-2015 |           0 |   3000 |       0 |     3000 |
|       4 |06-01-2015 |           0 |      0 |    1000 |    -1000 |
|       4 |06-01-2015 |       -1000 |      0 |    2000 |    -3000 |
|       4 |07-01-2015 |       -3000 |    500 |       0 |    -2500 |
|       5 |07-01-2015 |           0 |    500 |       0 |      500 |
|       5 |08-01-2015 |         500 |    500 |       0 |     1000 |
+---------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+---- -----+
```

I need balances and Open balances to be calculated by client_id and date order as shown above. Please help.

Comment: This is SQL. I see no dates here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how you can do it using dynamic variables

```
select 
s.client_id,
s.date,
s.credit,
s.debit,
s.balance
from
(
  select 
  t.client_id,
  t.date,
  t.credit,
  t.debit,
  @tot_credit := if(@prev_client = t.client_id, @tot_credit + t.credit,t.credit) as tot_cred,
  @tot_debit := if(@prev_client = t.client_id,@tot_debit + t.debit,t.debit) as tot_deb,
  @cur_balance := if(@prev_client = t.client_id,@cur_bal := @tot_credit - @tot_debit,t.credit-t.debit) as balance,
  @prev_client := t.client_id,
  @prev_credit := t.credit,
  @prev_debit := t.debit
  from(
    select * from stock order by client_id,date
  )t,(select @prev_client:=0,@cur_bal:=0,@prev_credit:=0,@prev_debit:=0,@tot_credit:=0,@tot_debit:= 0)r
)s
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f7c1/1)**

Comment: It's not working if there is second credit from the same client_id for the same date or different date.

Comment: Update the question with those sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Hi Abhik Chakraborty, I designed a report page on which I need 'open balance' too. Can you please help. Please check the updated sample data.

Comment: Please post a new question with the new desired output.

Comment: Please check the updated post here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828145/mysql-open-balance-credit-debit-balance

Answer (score 1):

Try operators

like

```
SELECT client_id,date,credit,debit,(credit-debit) as balance FROM  Stock;
```

Thanks.