# MySQL Open Balance Credit Debit Balance

Tags: mysql

I got a table named "Stock" as shown below.

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| client_id |       date   |       credit  |    debit|
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
|         1 |   01-01-2015 |            50 |       0 |
|         2 |   01-01-2015 |           250 |       0 |
|         2 |   01-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         2 |   02-01-2015 |             0 |     500 |
|         1 |   02-01-2015 |             0 |      40 |
|         1 |   02-01-2015 |             0 |      80 |
|         3 |   05-01-2015 |          3000 |       0 |
|         2 |   06-01-2015 |             0 |     350 |
|         4 |   06-01-2015 |             0 |    1000 |
|         4 |   06-01-2015 |             0 |    2000 |
|         4 |   07-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         5 |   07-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         5 |   08-01-2015 |           500 |       0 |
|         1 |   09-01-2015 |             0 |     100 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

The result I am expecting is something like:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+----------+
|client_id|  date     |Open_Balance | credit |  debit  | balance  |
+---------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+----------+
|       1 |01-01-2015 |           0 |     50 |       0 |       50 |
|       1 |02-01-2015 |          50 |      0 |      40 |       10 |
|       1 |02-01-2015 |          10 |      0 |      80 |      -70 |
|       1 |09-01-2015 |         -70 |      0 |     100 |     -170 |
|       2 |01-01-2015 |           0 |    250 |       0 |      250 |
|       2 |01-01-2015 |         250 |    500 |       0 |      750 |
|       2 |02-01-2015 |         750 |      0 |     500 |      250 |
|       2 |06-01-2015 |         250 |      0 |     350 |     -100 |  
|       3 |05-01-2015 |           0 |   3000 |       0 |     3000 |
|       4 |06-01-2015 |           0 |      0 |    1000 |    -1000 |
|       4 |06-01-2015 |       -1000 |      0 |    2000 |    -3000 |
|       4 |07-01-2015 |       -3000 |    500 |       0 |    -2500 |
|       5 |07-01-2015 |           0 |    500 |       0 |      500 |
|       5 |08-01-2015 |         500 |    500 |       0 |     1000 |
+---------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+---- -----+
```

I need balances and 'Open balances' to be calculated by client_id and date order as shown above. Please help.

Comment: how you are calculating `Open balances'` ?

Comment: Initial 'open balance' is zero for each client_id.

Comment: and how do you calculate balance

Comment: (opening balance + credit) - debit = balance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how you can do it..

```
select 
s.client_id,
s.date,
s.op_balance as Open_Balance,
s.credit,
s.debit,
s.balance
from
(
  select 
  t.client_id,
  t.date,
  t.credit,
  t.debit,
  @tot_credit := if(@prev_client = t.client_id, @tot_credit + t.credit,t.credit) as tot_cred,
  @tot_debit := if(@prev_client = t.client_id,@tot_debit + t.debit,t.debit) as tot_deb,
  @cur_bal := if(@prev_client = t.client_id, @tot_credit - @tot_debit,t.credit-t.debit) as balance,
  (@cur_bal + t.debit) - t.credit as op_balance,
  @prev_client := t.client_id
  from(
    select * from stock order by client_id,date
  )t,(select @prev_client:=0,@cur_bal:=0,@tot_credit:=0,@tot_debit:= 0,@open_balance:=0)r
)s
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f7c1/18)**

Also I have noticed that the same data you have date column which I have used to do the sort per client id, but its good to have datetime for date so that the sorting does not get confused with same date or may be a primary key in the table.

Answer (score 2):

First of all set two variables for open balance and balance;

```
mysql> set @balance = 0;

mysql> set @openBalance = 0;
```

then set id variable

```
mysql> set @id := (select client_id from Stock order by client_id asc limit 1);
```

and now run this query

```
select client_id,date,IF(client_id=@id,@balance:=@balance,@balance:=0),
@openBalance:=@balance as OpenBalance,credit,debit,@balance:=(credit+@openBalance)-debit as 
bal,@id:=client_id from Stock order by client_id,date;
```

Yeah since some data have same date and id, query may work different way so pls make some changes in your table definition such as rather than date you can make it date time and then sort accordingly.