# MySQL query for opening balance, debit, credit and closing balance for all accounts based on journal, receipts and payments table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate opening balance, DrAmount, CrAmount, Closing Balance for each account based on transaction saved in Journal, Receipts and Payments Table. I am working on a double entry accounting system project based on php and mysql.

Table fields of above said 3 tables is same and as follows:

```
id | date | bill_no |debit_account_id| credit_account_id | amount
```

Result I am expecting is -

```
account_id | OpeningBalance | Debit | Credit | ClosingBalance
```

I am not good at subqueries hence stucked at this point.

What I have done so far is getting balance from Journal table only by doing below query:

```
    SELECT a.ac_name, ifnull((SELECT sum(j.amt) FROM journal j WHERE j.from_ac_id=a.id),0) - ifnull((SELECT sum(j.amt) FROM journal j WHERE j.to_ac_id=a.id),0) as Balance FROM accounts a GROUP BY a.ac_name
```

[this is query result from journal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Oyx.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828145/mysql-open-balance-credit-debit-balance

Comment: P.Salmon Sir, please see my updated question, I also added a image

Answer (score -3):

Hire a professional, this kind of questions have a heavy answer